# how to stop repeat request in java webservice

Tags: java, web-services

I created a SOAP webservice which convert received xml to mail content and send. Now sometime user sent same request twice and the same mail were sent twice. How to stop this? I think I can create a table to store the content and eachtime when a request received first check the table content then proceed. Is that work? I guess in the process I have to lock the table should I use synchronized method? or other better ways? Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the `stateless` nature of the `HTTP protocol`, from [wikipedia.org](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stateless_protocol) you have the following statement :

> no information is retained by either sender or receiver, meaning that
>   each is unaware of the state of the other.

The behavior of your application is normal. What is happening, is up to the user, because in real life, you can send as many mails as you want.
Depending on your requirement, you can use a `database` or a `cache` to store the user actions to avoid duplicates requests.